# When to use static imports in java

Tags: java

When is it appropriate to perform a static import package.package.class ? Nothing seems to answer this question on Google.

> A static import allows you to write this:
>
> `out.print("The result is ");`
>   rather than this:
>
> `System.out.print("The result is ");`

This does not make sense to me. If I import that class why will its methods also not be imported?

Answer (score 5):

Using static imports allows you to turn this:

```
double r = Math.cos(Math.PI * theta);
```

into this:

```
double r = cos(PI * theta);
```

The static imports tells the class where these methods are coming from so you do not need to preceed the method with the class name when using static imports

Answer (score 1):

Try `import static java.lang.System.out;`. You aren't importing its' method, you're importing its' static `out` member variable.

Answer (score 0):

`static import` is a convenience. If you are repeatedly using `static` members of some class in your code, a static import will save you from writing as much.

`System.out.println` becoming `out.println` is probably one of the most common uses, due to its connection with console debugging and console applications in general. However, any class with static members (methods or fields) can be effectively used. If you make extensive use of `Math`, for example, statically importing that class would make your calls to your mathematics functions simpler. If you frequently make calls to methods of a singleton class, statically importing that class would let you go from `Singleton.INSTANCE.method()` to `INSTANCE.method()`.

As the static import is purely for convenience's sake, it may make more sense to ask when it's *inappropriate* to use, rather than when *to* use it. You shouldn't use static import when:

- You will create name collisions between multiple static imports (I believe javac will yell at you about collisions anyway, though)
- It will be unclear what class the static members you're using are coming from; `out.println` is familiar enough to a Java developer that they'll assume it's from `System` immediately... so don't statically import some *other* field named "out" which has a method "println"! `cos`, `sin`, `tan`, `pow`, and friends can be pretty obviously deduced to be from `Math`, especially in context.

In general, I wouldn't *recommend* statically importing from more than one class per file, simply to reduce confusion when reading code. "Is `foo(Bar b)` coming from the import of `Fizz` or `Buzz`? Or wait, is it being imported from somewhere else at all?!" is not the sort of question you want a future developer to ask themselves; and remember that it won't take long for *you* to forget all the design decisions you made for your own code, so be nice to yourself as well as others!

Comment: You stated:  "so don't statically import some other field named "out" which has a method "println"!"  How can a field have a method?  I always thought a class member was one or the other?

Comment: @IqbalHamid, In `System.out.println`, `out` is a static field of the `System` class. In this case, `out` is an instance of the `PrintStream` class, and therefore has methods of its own. Any field which is a class instance could have methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it anywhere however it might make code less readable. However there are exceptions, eg it is generally accepted practice to use static imports in JUnit tests

```
import static org.junit.Assert;

...

assertEquals(expected, actual);
```